# Passar parâmetros via GET e incluir mais parâmetros

Tags: php

Estou com uma página de consulta, onde pode se incluir diversos parâmetros nessa consulta.
Gostaria de concatenar mais parâmetros se já existir parâmetros nessa consulta.
Resumindo, pegar os parâmetros que já existem e concatenar se o usuário escolher mais algum.

`Ex:
<a href="?sexo=m">Masculino</a>
<a href="?cor=verde">Verde</a>`

Comment: O link é montado so com html? O segundo parâmetro e os demais são separados por `&`

Comment: É sim, mas aí eu teria que fazer ?sexo=m&cor=verde
Sem saber se o usuário teria escolhido a opção sexo Masculino

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 3):

Se a consulta veio por GET em um endereço semelhante a este:

```
http://site/page.php?b=1&c=2
```

E você quer que o link `<a href="?cor=verde">Verde</a>` receba junto `b=1&c=2`, você pode usar `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
//cria a variavel vazia
$qs = '';

//Verifica se QueryString é vazio, se não for então seta a variavel $qs
if (false === empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
   //O & no final é para separar as variaveis
   $qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&';
}
?>

<a href="?<?php echo $qs; ?>cor=verde">Verde</a>
```

Para evitar valores repetidos, você pode usar um array usando `parse_str` e `http_build_query`:

```
<?php
$qs = '';

if (false === empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
   $qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&';
}

//extrai a querystring para uma array/vetor
parse_str($qs, $output);

//Exibe o resultado
print_r($output);
?>

<?php
//Copia o output para não misturar os links
$link1 = $output;

//Cria o seu link com o valor cor=verde
$link1['cor'] = 'verde';
?>
<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($link1); ?>"></a>

<?php
//Copia o output para não misturar os links
$link2 = $output;

//Cria o seu link com o valor sexo=m
$link2['sexo'] = 'm';
?>
<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($link2); ?>"></a>
```

Isto irá evitar aparecer algo como:

```
?cor=verde&cor=verde
```

Então primeiro o usuário escolhe `cor=verde` e a url fica assim:

```
./page.php?cor=verde
```

Então ele escolhe `sexo=m` e a url fica assim:

```
./page.php?cor=verde&sexo=m
```

Comment: tem alguns erros, no início seria a função empty não é?

Comment: Não tenho muita experiência em operadores ternários, poderia explicar o que seria  empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '' : ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&');

Comment: @MateusCarvalho Editei a resposta e adicionei alguns comentários para facilitar e corrigi um erro nas ifs.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o  **&** no começo de um novo parâmetro.

```
   ....
    <a href="?sexo=m&cor=verde">Masculino e Verde</a>
    ....
```